# PHP: newbie question - variables inside a class?

Tags: php, class

i'm having this code:

```
class c_web
{
    var $root_fso;

    function __construct($webname)
    {
        $this->webname = $webname;
        $root_fso = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'};
    }

    function init($template_filename)
    {
        echo $root_fso;
    }

}
```

my question: what's wrong with the syntax with the $root_fso variable as it returns blank?

thanks

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. note the square brackets.

Comment: @ithcy: Curly braces are okay too, actually. But you are right, the square ones are preferred.

Comment: @nikic: I have never seen curly braces used to access array members in PHP. Ever. Can you provide evidence?

Comment: @ithcy: It's a little bit hidden, it is mentioned only in the string offset access section on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. On ideone: http://ideone.com/UoVbH

Comment: @nikic: OK, I learned something new about PHP today :) I can't find it documented anywhere, but I tested and you're correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ithcy: PHP is full of surprises :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly say `$this->root_fso` because PHP doesn't need you to declare a local variable so `$root_fso` is always going to refer to a local.  Use `$this->` when accessing fields of the class.

OTHER OBSERVATIONS:
Also `$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}` should be `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?  Also `$this->webname` refers to a field that is not defined, you should define it.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}` is perfectly valid syntax and does the exactly same thing as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Still it shall not by used, by convention. This syntax is near to deprecation and actually was deprecated for some time in PHP 5.3 I think.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @nikic, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

It's `$this->root_fso`. In PHP, the `$this->` is necessary to access any class member.

Answer (score 0):

It is a class variable so you have to reference with `$this`

```
class c_web
{
    var $root_fso;

    function __construct($webname)
    {
        $this->webname = $webname;
        $this->root_fso = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }

    function init($template_filename)
    {
        echo $this->root_fso;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

class c_web
{
    var $root_fso;

    function __construct($webname)
    {
        $this->webname = $webname;
        $this->root_fso = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'};
    }

    function init($template_filename)
    {
        echo $this->root_fso;
    }

}

$a = new c_web("a");
$a->init("a");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two things wrong here.

To start with, `$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'};` should be `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Second, the value of `$root_fso` changes only in __construct.  You would need to change the second line of your __construct function to: `$this->root_fso  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`